# How to easier to split csv data by substring using python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

[Finally I want to split clearly like this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8IA4.png)
*NOT replace, I want to **SPLIT** and not just using "," to split
MUST according to substring to split it
I have a csv like:

```
date, time, ID1, ID2, ID3, "Action=xxx, ProdCode=XXXX, Cmd=xxx, Price=xxxxx, Qty=xxx, TradedQty=xxx, Validity=xxx, Status=xxx, AddBy=xxxxxx, TimeStamp=xxx, ClOrderId=xxx, ChannelId=xxx",x,x,ID4

date, time, ID1, ID2, ID3, "Action=xxx, RetCode=xxx, ProdCode=xxxx, Cmd=xxx, Price=xxxx, Qty=xxx, TradedQty=0, Validity=xxx, Status=xxx, ExtOrderNo=xxxxx, Ref=0, AddBy=xxxxx, Gateway=xxxxx, TimeStamp=xxx, ClOrderId=xxx",x,x,ID4

date, time, ID1, ID2, ID3, "Action=xx, RetCode=xx, ProdCode=xxx, Cmd=xx, Price=xxx, Qty=x, TradedQty=x, Status=xxx, ExtOrderNo=xxx, Ref=xxx, AddBy=xx, Gateway=xxx, TimeStamp=xxx",x,x,ID4

date,time,ID1,ID2,ID3,"Action=xxx, ProdCode=xxx, Cmd=xxx, Price=xxx, Qty=x, ExtOrderNo=xxx, TradeNo=xxx, Ref=@xxx, AddBy=xxx, Gateway=xxx",x,x,ID4
```

How can I easier to split to different column by the string before "="?
And if there is no relevant words in the row, the row is empty
Or add "word=," or simply add "," at that position
Final Result LIKE:

```
date, time, ID1, ID2, ID3, "Action=xxx, **RetCode=,** ProdCode=XXXX, Cmd=xxx, Price=xxxxx, Qty=xxx, TradedQty=xxx, Validity=xxx, Status=xxx, **ExtOrderNo=,**  **TradeNo=,** **Ref=,** AddBy=xxxxxx, **Gateway=,** TimeStamp=xxx, ClOrderId=xxx, ChannelId=xxx",x,x,ID4

date, time, ID1, ID2, ID3, "Action=xxx, RetCode=xxx, ProdCode=xxxx, Cmd=xxx, Price=xxxx, Qty=xxx, TradedQty=0, Validity=xxx, Status=xxx,    ExtOrderNo=xxxxx, **TradeNo=,**  Ref=0, AddBy=xxxxx, Gateway=xxxxx, TimeStamp=xxx, ClOrderId=xxx **ChannelId=,**",x,x,ID4

date, time, ID1, ID2, ID3, "Action=xxx, RetCode=xx, ProdCode=xxx, Cmd=xx, Price=xxx, Qty=x, TradedQty=x, **Validity=,** Status=xxx, ExtOrderNo=xxx, **TradeNo=,** Ref=xxx, AddBy=xx, Gateway=xxx, TimeStamp=xxx **ClOrderId=,** **ChannelId=,**",x,x,ID4

date,time,ID1,ID2,ID3,"Action=xxx, **RetCode=,** ProdCode=xxx, Cmd=xxx, Price=xxx, Qty=x, **TradedQty=,** **Validity=,** **Status=,** ExtOrderNo=xxx,  TradeNo=xxx, Ref=@xxx, AddBy=xxx, Gateway=xxx **TimeStamp=,** **ClOrderId=,** **ChannelId=,**",x,x,ID4
```

p.s. above just some example of the csv, maybe have other words=xxx, how can I easier to split it
I want clearly in csv or excel show which data exists and which data does not

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand 100%, but let me try to help.
The focus points are:

```
# import the pandas library and alias as pd
import pandas as pd

# read a csv with the example data
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", sep=",", quoting=False, header = None)

# replace any values that match the pattern "something=value" with "value"
df.replace(to_replace=r"^(.*)=", value="", regex=True, inplace=True)
# save to a new csv file:
df.to_csv("new_data.csv", sep=",", header = None, index = False)
```

Comment: "SPLIT" not REPLACE.